# Woher kommt "pitsche-patsche" (nass)?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Früher habe ich

> pitsche-patsche nass

immer mal wieder in Mittel-/Norddeutschland gehört. Ich habe es aber nie irgendwo gelesen, deswegen weiß ich nicht mal, ob ich es richtig geschrieben habe.
Bisher habe ich es nur als verniedlichendes Adjektiv zur Verstärkung von *nass* gehört, z.B. wenn es gegenüber Kindern oder Tieren gesagt wird. Es soll hervorheben, dass jemand oder etwas besonders nass ist.

Beispiel:

> Du bist ja pitsche-patsche nass.
>
> Du bist ja komplett nass/völlig durchnässt.

**Meine Frage ist**, woher kommt *pitsche-patsche*, was ist die Etymologie des Wortes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich schätze mal stark, dass das lautmalerisch ist.

"Patschen" ist lautmalerisch. Und das hat ja auch eine Bedeutung, in der Wasser eine Rolle spielt - [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/patschen) gibt die Bedeutungen

> (mit Hilfsverb ›hat‹) mit der (flachen) Hand, den Füßen klatschend an, auf, in etw. schlagen

und

> (mit Hilfsverb ›ist‹) durch, in etw., besonders Schlamm, Wasser, (stampfend) gehen, waten, dass es spritzt

Für die Etymologie von patschen gibt Pfeifer (ebd.) an:

> **patschen** Vb. ‘ein klatschendes Geräusch machen’ (15. Jh.), eigentl. ‘den Laut patsch verursachen’; zur lautmalenden Interjektion patsch. Patsch m. ‘klatschender Schlag, Straßenschmutz’ (Ende 16. Jh.). Patsche f. ‘flacher Gegenstand zum Schlagen’ (16. Jh.), ‘klatschender Schlag, Straßenschmutz’ (Anfang 18. Jh.); übertragen in der Patsche sein, sitzen, stecken ‘in einer fatalen, unangenehmen Lage, in Not, Bedrängnis, Verlegenheit sein’ (Anfang 18. Jh.). Patschhand f. ‘die einschlagende Hand, Handschlag’ (Anfang 18. Jh.), vgl. früher bezeugtes Patschhändlein (16. Jh.). ...

"patschnass" ist dann wohl 'so nass, wie man durch das patschen [durch das patschende, also spritzende Wasser] wird" oder, wie Carsten S im Kommentar anmerkt 'so nass, dass die Kleidung ein patschendes Geräusch  macht'.

Und "pitschpatschnass" ist dann wohl eine lautmalerische Erweiterung.

Comment: *Eins, zwei, drei, vier, fünf, sechs, sieben, \\ in der Schule wird geschrieben,\\ in der Schule wird gelacht,\\ bis der Lehrer pitsch-patsch macht.* - wer's noch kennt ist alt genug ;)

Comment: Zu dem Patschen des Wassers, durch das man nass wird, kommt vielleicht noch das Patschen durchnässter Kleidung.

Comment: @Takkat Bei mir hieß das immer "Bis der Lehrer Faxen macht" :-)

Answer (score 4):

Das ist ganz einfach ein onomatopoetischer Ausdruck, also eine sprachliche Nachahmung eines außersprachlichen Schallereignisses, so wie »Tick-Tack« für »Uhr«, »Wau-Wau« für einen Hund oder »holterdipolter« um Gepolter nachzuahmen.

Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoesie